# Java gui not uppdatring immediately

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a gui crated with Netbeans with a button and a cardlayout.
This button have a actionlistener registered to itself and when pressed it runs an external program with process.waitFor();

What i want is when you press the button the gui should swap a card in the cardlayout and run the external program.
what realy happens is when i press the button the external program starts and when it is finnished then the gui swaps cards.

Do i need to call an uppdatemethod on the gui or something?

Comment: Code Please, that is being used by you, will be much appreciated.

Comment: @GagandeepBali - honestly, in this case it's not needed; his question tells you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @BrianRoach : Exactly to point him/her in the right direction, what is to be used and where that is to be used, I guess code will be a good option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your call to your external program in another Thread:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    // call to ext. program
    }
});
t.start();
return;
```

Comment: Watch out that AWT is not thread-safe, thus you should ensure that only a single thread runs the AWT code simultaneously (except some part are thread-safe but you gotta to know them). You can do this using `synchronized` or by forcing everything linked to AWT to happen in the AWT-Thread by calling `SwintUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)`. Also if you access the same field from different threads make it `volatile` or ´synchronized`.

Comment: I used the method invokeLater, as it seemed to be the right way to go. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

The GUI events are managed by a single thread. You're stopping that thread from doing its job (updating the display) by running your external program and waiting for it to finish; since you're doing that in an event handler, that's the thread that's executing your code.

You need to have a separate thread manage that, or use a timer checking to see if it's finished, etc.